# Issue pushing item to the end of a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, append

I have the following code...

```
if ($email_selection == "primary") {

     $default_select = "<option value=''>Select Email</option>";
     $select_1 = "selected";
     $to_array[] = $profile_primary_email;

} elseif ($email_selection == "secondary") {

     $default_select = "<option value=''>Select Email</option>";
     $select_2 = "selected";
     $to_array[] = $profile_primary_email;

} elseif ($email_selection == "both") {

     $default_select = "<option value=''>Select Email</option>";
     $select_3 = "selected";
     $to_array[] = $profile_primary_email . ',' . $profile_secondary_email;

} 

if ($manual_email != "") {

    $to_array[] = $manual_email;

}

$to_array_count = count($to_array);

$to = $to_array["0"];

for ($v = 1; $v < $to_count; $v++) {

    $to = $to . ',' . $to_array[$v];

}
```

The function of this code is to get the value of a select input, and based on the select input's value push an email address to the end of `$to_array`. Then the script makes a string of each email seperated by a comma which will later be used as the `$to` in the PHP `mail()` function.

For some reason, the select field contains any value, the email address contained in `$manual_email` is not appended to the array. If there is no value to the select field, however, `$manual_email` is appended to the empty array normally.

Comment: `$to_array[0]` and `$to_array['0']` are not the same in PHP.

Comment: Removing or adding the quotation marks doesn't change the function of the script. I have always used them interchangeably and been just fine. Regardless, I have the same issue either way.

Comment: just to clarify that last paragraph, are you saying that `$manual_email` is not being appended if `$to_array` contains some data?

Comment: What is `$manual_email` anyways? Looks undefined.

Comment: Are we supposed to assume that there is a test for form submission wrapped around this code?

Comment: @PHPglue, yes there is. And `$manual_email` is defined by post data. Obviously if I was asking, it was defined. It didn't seem prudent to include a mass of unnecessary code.

Comment: @khuderm, yes. If the select field contained any data, `$manual_email` would not be appended. As detailed in the answer, `implode()` was a far more efficient option anyways, and solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to rewrite all your code, but:

```
$to_array_count = count($to_array);

$to = $to_array["0"];

for ($v = 1; $v < $to_count; $v++) {

   $to = $to . ',' . $to_array[$v];

}
```

should probably just be:

```
$to = implode(',', $to_array);
```

Not really sure why you wouldn't use a `foreach` loop anyways, if you were going to do it the looney way.

Comment: You're right. That way was inefficient, your solution works well. Thanks.